# Question about Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am currently a proof of Bolzano Weierstrass from Abbot. I agree with everything in the proof. But, one thing I don't like is that why do we know that there is one particular half which contains infinitely many elements? For example, in the first construction of $I_1$ is the proof they choose the half of the interval containing infinitely many elements, but what is bugging me is that is it possible for the two halves to contain infinitely many elements?  [image]

Comment: Note that it doesn't say **the** half that has infinitely many.  It says **a** half.  It is possible for both to have infinitely elements, but it doesn't matter; you just have to pick one of the two that does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We care about one half at a time to have infinitely many elements but it is possible that both halves have infinitely many elements.

Take for example the sequence  $x_n= \frac{n}{n+1}$ if $n=2k+1$ and $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ if $n=2k$ .

$x_n \in [0,1]$ and $x_n \in [0,1/2]$ for $n=2k$ and $x_n \in [1/2,1]$ for $n=2k+1$.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Really illuminating example.

Comment: you are welcome